# Is there a way to create a case-like IF statement in Python/Jupyter to monitor substrings in Tweets using Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am attempting to monitor several businesses Twitter accounts by exporting tweets to a .csv to look at the positivity or negativity of Tweets that include the name of the business, which will then be visualised.

To make it easier for myself I'm only assigning each Tweet one number, between 1 (negative) - 10 (positive), however the code I've written doesn't give any feedback (remains at 0), gets stuck in a For Loop, or gets a Syntax Error.

Using Jupyter notebook I've tried to create a 10 line If/Elif statement - due to Python not having a case statement, and inserted this code both in the 'get Tweets' method as well as the 'write csv' method.

**Get Tweets**

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

query = "ASOS"

language = "en"

results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, count=100)

for tweet in results:
    if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.text):
        print(tweet.user.screen_name,"Tweeted:",tweet.text,**rating**)
        print()
```

**Write CSV**

```
import csv

api = tweepy.API(auth)

csvFile = open('ASOS with emojis1.csv', 'a')

csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, count=100)

for tweet in results:
if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.text):
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text, **rating**])

csvFile.close()
```

**If/Elif Statement I've written**

```
rating = '0'

if 'abysmal' or 'appalling' or 'dreadful' or 'awful' or 'terrible' or 'very bad' or 'really bad' or '' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '1')
            elif 'rubbish' or 'unsatisfactory' or 'bad' or 'poor' or '' or '' or ':(' or '):' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '2')
            elif 'quite bad' or 'pretty bad' or 'somewhat bad' or 'below average' or '' or '' or '☹️' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '3')
            elif 'mediocre' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '4')
            elif 'average' or 'not bad' or 'fair' or 'alright' or 'ok' or 'satisfactory' or 'fine' or 'somewhat good' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' or 'omg' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '5')
            elif 'quite good' or 'decent' or 'above average' or 'pretty good' or 'good' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '6')
            elif 'great' or 'gr8' or 'really good' or 'rlly good' or 'very good' or 'v good' or '' or '☺️' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' ':)' or '(:' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '7')
            elif 'awesome' or 'fantastic' or '' or '' or '' or '' or '❤' or '♥' or '' or '' or '✅' or '' or '' or '' or '✨' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '8')
            elif 'superb' or 'brilliant' or 'incredible' or 'excellent' or 'oustanding' or '' or '' or '' or '' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '9')
            elif 'perfect' in tweet.text:
                (rating = '10')
            else:
                (rating = 'N/A')
```

Expected: Produces .csv file with various numbers in

Actual: (rating = '1') SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditionals are not working properly. To chain a conditional:

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3]

# Note that the full condition must be specified for
# each desired conditional
if 1 in mylist or 2 in mylist or 3 in mylist:
    print("True")

# True
```

The issue with what you are using is that you are approaching the logic the way you would *say* it rather than how the interpreter reads it. As an example:

```py
if 'a' or 'b':
    print('True')

# True
```

Populated strings act as `True` and will evaluate your condition as such, so a modification should be made such that the entire conditional is specified:

```py
# Evaluates to True, though it's not what you want
if 'a' and 'b' in 'bc':
    print(True) # This is not what you want, but 'a' is read as 'true'
# True

if 'a' in 'bc' and 'b' in 'bc':
    print(True)
# Doesn't print True because 'a' in 'bc' is False
```

The `any` function could help here, as it will look if any of the values evaluate to `True`:

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3]

if any([i in mylist for i in range(2,5)]):
    print("True")

# True
```

Furthermore, there's no need for the parentheses around variable assignment:

```py
if 'abysmal' in tweet.text or 'horrible' in tweet.text:
    rating = 0

elif ...:
    rating = 1

# So on and so forth
```

Comment: Incredible thank you, I'm the only one using the code and it's only for a temporary project so I don't need it to 'look' too nice. This has been perfect.